# Access query count by months

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables - 
"club members" table with 3 fields For example:

```
"Member_ID",   "Date_Of_Birth"
         1         13/4/1980              
         2         20/4/1990
         3         30/12/1970
         4         20/11/1960
```

"months list" table with the 1 field for example:

```
   "Month"  
   4-2017
   5-2017
   ...
   11-2017

   12-2017
   ...
   4-2018
   ...
   11-2018
   12-2018
```

I wish to generate a query that displays
Month , Number_Of_Birthdays

for example:

```
 4-2017     2  
   5-2017     0  
   ...  
   11-2017    1 
   12-2017    1  
   ... 
   4-2018     2  
   ...  
   11-2018    1  
   12-2018    1
```

How can I do it in access?

Thank you

Comment: can you please provide this example with table structure, its clumsy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `inner join`  and aggregate function `count`

As you edit your Question so try below query,remember date formating is a major issue here so keep it same format

```
select ML.Month,Number_Of_Birthdays_Of_Club_Memebers   from

    (
        select format(Member_Date_Of_Birth,"mm-yyyy") as  month_number,count(Member_ID) as Number_Of_Birthdays_Of_Club_Memebers  
        from club_members
        group by format(Member_Date_Of_Birth,"mm-yyyy")
    )as T1
    inner join months_list as ML
    T1.month_number=ML.Month
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you. I tried it and the query does not return results. I uploaded a file with the tables and query [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uCTm8FLWlchwn4EXKlJZeC5FzXmZY55u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I do not understand the join, The list of Month_list has no connection to Club_Member table. It is used only to get list of months and to calculate how many club members have birthday in this months. I mean it is general list to get months values for calculations.

Comment: I thought to define a query with no join, Just 2 tables but I do not understand how to define the conditions and grouping, thank you for your help.

Comment: edited a little bit check please i can modify again if it fails to answer your question

Comment: Maybe I will try just to calculate number of birthdays per month (with out the member join date condition)?

Comment: @user3340983 i have another version of query please check that one also and please give upvote and accept answer if it helps to you

Comment: Still not getting the expected results. I will try to modify my question.

Comment: I modified the question so it will be less complected. Can you help me?

Comment: Hello Thank you for help. It did not work for me. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want count the members as per join date.

```
Select b.Month_Date, Count(a.*) as Total_Members
From Club_Members as a INNER Join Month_List as b 
ON a.Member_Join_Date=b.Month_Date
Group BY  B.month_Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT Month_Date, sum(MemberCount) 
  FROM (
SELECT c.Member_ID, c.Member_Join_Date, m.Month_Date,CASE WHEN c.Member_Join_Date < m.Month_Date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END MemberCount 
  FROM club_members c, months_list m  
 ) s
GROUP BY Month_Date
```